# WinDbg Time Travel Debugging (TTD) fails to attach to 32-bit process (Outlook.exe)

Tags: debugging, outlook, office365, windbg

I get an error (see below) when I attempt to attach to the process Outlook.exe

We're running O365 
32-bit Outlook 
64-Bit Win10

When running WinDbg, I run it as Administrator.

**Error: Injecting into guest process failed with exitcode: 4294967295 - 0xFFFFFFFF
This may be an indication of a privileges problem or that the process is
already under tracing control and needs to be restarted.**

** COMPLETE .OUT FILE ** 
Release: 1.11.138.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Initializing Time Travel Debugging for Attach to 3900
Time: 07/07/2023 14:16:36
OS:10.0.19045 EDITION:x64

SessionID: 204EFD6E-F21C-49C8-92E2-1FC2224AB422

   (TTD::ManageTTDTrace:2729)
Running 
   (TTD::StartGuestProcess:1512)
Group tracing GUID: A4E27785-6D06-43C4-B4A9-A66F310EB8B5

Running "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\TTD\wow64\TTDInject.exe" /duration 1 /InjectMode LoaderForCombinedRecording /ClientParams "37 C:\Users\home\Documents\OUTLOOK14.run 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 c06001 0" /RecordScenario 268435457 /attach 3900 -TraceFileHandle 2d74 -GuestEventHandle 4b60 -ClientEventHandle 6814 -ActiveEventHandle 6790 -MutexHandle 6720 -CommunicationBufferHandle 623c -SharedSequenceMutexHandle 6684 -SharedSequenceBufferHandle 6724 /TelemetryFeatureSessionId "204EFD6E-F21C-49C8-92E2-1FC2224AB422"
   (TTD::StartGuestProcess:1959)
Microsoft (R) TTDInject 1.01.11
Release: 1.11.138.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

TTDLoader Params:
 LauncherDll = TTDLoader
 ClientDll   = TTDRecordCPU
 ClientEntry = InitializeNirvanaClient
 ClientParams= 37 C:\Users\home\Documents\OUTLOOK14.run 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 c06001 0
 Attach
WaitForMain is off
Allocated processors:32, running threads:76.
Loader TTDLoader.dll injected at 0x5C110000 0x8000 -- .reload  TTDLoader.dll=0x5C110000,0x8000

Injection by thread was incomplete. Status: 2156436999
 --> Client Initialization failed.
RecordingEngine initialization status 'ErrorVcpuInitializationFailed' with message:
 --> Error: TTDWriter Initialize: failed to initialize the TTDRecordCPU client
RecordVcpu initialization status 'ErrorGettingNtdllApiAddresses' with message:
 --> Error: GetNtdllAPIAddresses() failed for KiUserExceptionDispatcher
Loader initialization status ClientInitFailed' with message:
 --> Client Initialization failed.
Error: Injecting into guest process failed with exitcode: 4294967295 - 0xFFFFFFFF
 This may be an indication of a privileges problem or that the process is
 already under tracing control and needs to be restarted.

   (TTD::StartGuestProcess:2012)
Error: Client initialization failed status:4294967295
   (TTD::InitiateGuestProcess:2541)
Trace dumped to C:\Users\home\Documents\OUTLOOK14.run
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run both processes under the same security context - if you run Outlook with admin privileges you need to run the `WinDbg` with admin privileges too.

Make sure that both processes are run under the same security context. See [Process Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights) for more information.

Comment: I'm running WinDbg under as Administrator, but not Outlook.   I'll try that!!

Comment: Unfortunately, running both Outlook.exe and WinDbg as Administrator yielded the same result.   I posted the contents of the log.